# Generate simple html based on jasmine-allure-reporter

Tags: jasmine, protractor, report, allure

I'm using jasmine-allure-reporter and the report is simply awesome. Only complaint over the reporter is that I miss option to enable only failed screenshots to be saved and possibility to send it via e-mail.

I know that is not possible:
 [How to send an email of allure report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960081/how-to-send-an-email-of-allure-report)

My question is whether I can somehow generate a simple html file with few data based on the allure reports, so that I'll be able to send it via e-mail to relevant people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you have added this in your conf file:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000);
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        allureReport: {
            resultsDir: 'allure-results'
        }
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64');
            }, 'image/png')();
            done();
        });
    });

}
```

After running the files , go to allure-results where you can see the screenshots and xml reports.

Copy-Paste the folder i.e. allure-results to \node_modules\jasmine-allure-reporter where you can see a pom.xml file.

> Install Maven in your machine (This is mandatory)

Now from same path i.e. \node_modules\jasmine-allure-reporter run the following command

```
mvn site -Dallure.results_pattern=allure-results
```

After Successfull run of above command,

> Go to

\node_modules\jasmine-allure-reporter\target\site\allure-maven-plugin

and open index.html

This is how it looks:

[image: Report]

Comment: What about screenshots made only on test FAIL? Is that possible to setup in jasmine-allure-reporter?

Comment: Manually you can create. But that will be a huge task. How many test cases fail generally? what is the range?

Comment: Main problem with allure saving all the screenshots is space on the server. Once a huge amount of test runs will be done it will eat up space quite quickly. Currently the report needs approx. 29 MB of space. Huge by any means.

Comment: The screenshots are taking lot of space. You can generate report without screenshot as well, if size is problem.

Comment: That is exactly what we need, but still to have screenshots of only failed tests. How can I configure that?

Comment: You need to manually take those failed screenshots and xml reports and then generate html report.

Comment: it has one option as : var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
   captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true
});

Comment: This is exactly what we need. You are the greatest! Thank you!

Comment: Enjoy :-) have a great day ahead

Comment: What is "allure" in the below code?                                                                         `allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () `

Comment: How to add the environment properties and values

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. It takes screenshots of only failed tests.

```
var originalAddExpectationResult = jasmine.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult;
jasmine.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult = function () {
    if (!arguments[0]) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
            }, 'image/png')();
        })
    }
    return originalAddExpectationResult.apply(this, arguments);
};

var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
    resultsDir: 'allure-results'
}));
```