# Setting up html report with Jasmine & Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, bdd

I'm new to BDD and Jasmine. I have been following some tutorials and one feature I really like is the HTML Reporter that comes with it.

I'm trying to set Jasmine in a project running Node.js. I've followed their instructions for installing the npm module, [found on their Github page](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm)

I am able to run tests on the console, but I'm looking to also have the HTML reporter running those tests. I tried to include the static example HTML but that doesn't work.

I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue. I'm starting to think that there is no solution for displaying Jasmine HTML reports with Node.js

My aim is to run `jasmine` in the console and be able to then access the report without having to run any extra tool, such as Allure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate simple html based on jasmine-allure-reporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621567/generate-simple-html-based-on-jasmine-allure-reporter)

Comment: I updated the description a bit. No extra tools, such as Allure, can be used in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an HTML report you may use a package that generates it for you.

You can search directly into the NPM website for one that you most like or you can use my suggestion https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-pretty-html-reporter

The setup is very simple:

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var HtmlReporter = require('jasmine-pretty-html-reporter').Reporter;
var jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfigFile('./spec/support/jasmine.json');

// options object
jasmine.addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
  path: path.join(__dirname,'results')
}));

jasmine.execute();
```

The generated page is like this sample: https://stuisme.github.io/jasmine-pretty-html-reporter/sample-reports/report-passing.html

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at it and it seems to do what I need. I'm struggling to understand where those settings go and how to launch the tests