# Is there a way to export Allure Report to a single html file? To share with the team

Tags: python, automation, frameworks, allure

Right now, I am generating the Allure Report through the terminal by running the command: **allure serve {folder that contains the json files}**, but with this way the HTML report will only be available to my local because

1. The json files that generated the report are in my computer
2. I ran the command through the terminal (if i kill the terminal, the report is gone)

I have tried: Saving the Allure Report as *Webpage, Complete*, but the results did not reflect to the page, all i was seeing was blank fields.

So, what im trying to to do is after I execute the command to generate the report, I want to have an **html file** of the report that i can store, save to my computer or send through email, so i do not have to execute the command to see the previous reports. (as much as possible into 1 html file)

Comment: Follow my answer to the same question on stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960081/how-to-send-an-email-of-allure-report/64011632#64011632

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's doesn't work because allure report as you seen is not a simple Webpage, you could not save it and send as file to you team. It's a local Jetty server instance, serves generated report and then you can open it in the browser.

Here for your needs some solutions:

1. One server(your local PC, remote or some CI environment), where you can generate report and share this for you team. (server should be running alltime)
2. Share allure report folder as files({folder that contains the json files}) to teammates, setup them allure tool, and run command allure server on them local(which one).

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i've been thinking, have my team install allure and put all the files that generates the report in s3.

Answer (score 3):

Since release 2.24, you can generate single file reports using the `--single-file` option:

```
$ allure generate --single-file path/to/allure-results
```

Comment: This working like a charm. Details here. https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/pull/2072

Answer (score 2):

I've made a tool to build whole `allure generate`' result folder into a single html file.
https://github.com/MihanEntalpo/allure-single-html-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use this docker container to render and export an emailable report
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#customize-emailable-report

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can generate HTML report.

You can use the command `allure generate <alluredir>` to create html files. This folder you could send around, but you can only directly open the index.html file with `Edge` or `Firefox`.

[source](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/755#issuecomment-420376918)

Answer (score 0):

Allure report generates html in temp folder after execution and you can upload it to one of the server like netlify and it will generate an url to share.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we need to deploy our allure-report folder to a server. So Navigate to **allure-report** folder, simply drag and drop to [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/). That would generate a link that can be shared with anyone to access. However, this is not recommended to deploy like this if our allure-report folder has confidential data