# Allures tests display historic trends and send mails

Tags: testing, automation, webdriver-io, allure

I am using webdriver io to run some tests. I am very new to this and wanted to know:

Can the allure send mails or broadcast reports somewhere for public visibility in my organisation. The current project is running in my machine.

For some odd reason the allure report generated does not display any trends,I know for a fact it stores new files in allure-reports folder,but are those automatically pulled in the allure-results which basically renders the HTML file!?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960081/how-to-send-an-email-of-allure-report - as of now you cannot send emails of allure reports

Comment: thanks @demouser123